# Trouble with matrix in Python

Tags: python, class, methods, matrix, outofrangeexception

I'm trying to transcribe my Java classes to Python. The last one was the Warshall Algorithm, but when I run the aplication, I get this error:

```
C:\Python33\python.exe C:/Users/Joloch/PycharmProjects/Varios/Warshall.py
Inserte un valor para n (la matriz será cuadrada, por lo que es nxn):
3
Inserte un dato en la posición 0 0 :
Inserte un dato en la posición 0 1 :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Joloch/PycharmProjects/Varios/Warshall.py", line 93, in <module>
    Warshall().main()
  File "C:/Users/Joloch/PycharmProjects/Varios/Warshall.py", line 59, in main
    obj.Matriz[x][y] = Dato
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is the code, I appreciate a lot if you can tell me what I'm doing wrong:

```
from Tools.Scripts.treesync import raw_input

class Warshall(object):
    pass

    Matriz = [],[]
    Lado = 0

    def __init__(self):
        return

    @classmethod
    def Funcion(self, A, B, C):
        if ((self.Matriz[A][B] == 1) ^ (self.Matriz[A][C] == 1) & (self.Matriz[C][B] == 1)):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    def main(self):
        obj = Warshall()
        Dato = 0
        x = 0
        y = 0
        z = 0
        Uno = 0
        Dos = 0
        Tres = 0
        Cuatro = 0
        print("Inserte un valor para n (la matriz será cuadrada, por lo que es nxn): ")
        obj.Lado = int(raw_input(""))
        obj.Matriz = [obj.Lado],[obj.Lado]
        while x < obj.Lado:
            while y < obj.Lado:
                print("Inserte un dato en la posición", x, y,": ")
                try:
                    Dato = int(raw_input())
                except TypeError:
                    print()
                obj.Matriz[x][y] = Dato
                y += 1

            while z <= obj.Lado - 1:
                while Uno <= obj.Lado - 1:
                    while Dos <= obj.Lado - 1:
                        obj.Matriz[Uno][Dos] = obj.Funcion(Uno, Dos, z)
                        Dos += 1
                    Uno += 1
                z += 1

            print()
            print("Matriz de adyacencia correspondiente: ")

            while Tres < obj.Lado:
                while Cuatro < obj.Lado:
                    print(obj.Matriz[Tres][Cuatro])
                    print()
                    Cuatro += 1
                Tres += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Warshall().main()
```

Comment: Hmmm... Why do you a) bother to define `__init__` when you don't do anything in that method, and b) why is your `main()` function *inside* of your class?

Comment: a) Habit, I usually put a constructor in every class where I use methods.

b) I'm new at Python, so I thought that it might be like Java, because I saw a couple of examples with main methods.

Answer (score 2):

This code is structured in a, ah, curious way which makes in hard to sort out what exactly is going on.

The source of your error is that `obj.Matriz` is a tuple with two length 1 lists in it, not a `Lado` by `Lado` by array as you expect.  If you print out `obj.Matriz` you will get `([5], [5])` (if `Lado == 5`).

Try something more like

```
obj.Matriz = [[0 for j in range(obj.Lado)] for k in range(obj.Lado)]
```

which will give you `Lado` lists of length `Lado` filled with `0`.  If you are doing numeric work you might want to look into `numpy` as well.

Comment: The same error, but now on this line:
`if ((self.Matriz[A][B] == 1) ^ (self.Matriz[A][C] == 1) & (self.Matriz[C][B] == 1)):`

Maybe the causes are the symbols ^ and &... in my Java class that line is:
`if ((Matriz[K][Q] == 1) || ((Matriz[K][J] == 1) && (Matriz[J][Q] == 1)))`

Which operators are similar to "&&" and "||"?

Comment: 1) It is impossible to read code in comments 2) `and` and `or` and 3) that is a sufficiently different question that you should start a new question.